# Spring/JMS listen to many destinations with one thread

Tags: multithreading, spring, jms

I have a spring/JMS heavy application in which I have multiple listener containers each listening to a different topic or queue.  I would like to reduce the number of threads I use to receive messages, and the number of threads I use to process messages for certain groups of queues/topics.

Is there any way to do this without using message selectors?  I saw spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer has a way to provide a task executor.  However, the [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setTaskExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor%29) claims

> 'A plain thread pool does not add much
>   value, as this listener container will
>   occupy a number of threads for its
>   entire lifetime'

I don't really need JMS transactions, or really even care if I get multiple messages.  Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: Which JMS implementation are you using ?

Comment: I am using ActiveMQ 5.4.0 with spring 3.0.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out activemq virtual destinations. They allow you to multiplex multiple destinations through a single receiver.

http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html

Comment: Wow, that's awesome.  The article was particularly pleasing since it confirmed much frustration with durable topics.